# PNPM modules dependencies aren't linked to the node_modules folder

Tags: react-native, pnpm

The dependencies of the `@react-native-community/cli` module aren't linked to the node_module folder.

I'm trying to create a pnpm monorepo with React native, but the dependencies of the `@react-native-community/cli` aren't linked to the node_module folder.
Here are the `@react-native-community/cli` module dependencies:

`"dependencies": { "@react-native-community/cli-clean": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-config": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-doctor": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-hermes": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-server-api": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-tools": "11.2.0", "@react-native-community/cli-types": "11.2.0", "chalk": "^4.1.2", "commander": "^9.4.1", "execa": "^5.0.0", "find-up": "^4.1.0", "fs-extra": "^8.1.0", "graceful-fs": "^4.1.3", "prompts": "^2.4.0", "semver": "^6.3.0" },`

They are all missing inside the node_modules folder.

I have tried `shamefully-hoist=true` in the .npmrc config file but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need hoisting, create a `.npmrc` file in the root of you workspace with the following content:

```
node-linker=hoisted
```

`shamefully-hoist` will also work but as far as I know react native doesn't work with symlinks at the moment.

Comment: React 0.72 has support for symlinks, although you have to enable it in a config file.  It will be the default in 0.73.   https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/06/21/0.72-metro-package-exports-symlinks.  I haven't tried it myself.